# Values of uninitialized array being overwritten in block scope

Tags: arrays, c, gcc, initialization, compiler-optimization

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int send_buf[4];
    if(1){
        int hello[5]={1,2,3,4,5};        
    }
    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
        printf("%d ",send_buf[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:** 1 2 3 4

On executing the above C code,  the output always resulted in the values assigned to the array `hello` in block scope. However, if any reference (say printing the address of `send_buf`) is made prior to printing the array `send_buf`, the output results in the usual indeterminate values.

**Can someone please explain why are the values of `send_buf` being overwritten when the memory for `send_buf` has already been allocated on the stack?**

Is it some kind of GCC compiler optimization of delaying the allocation of an uninitialized array until its referenced?

Compiled using GCC version 9.3.0.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like an obvious optimization.  If the arrays `send_buf` and `hello` are never used at the same time, then why not have them share the same memory?

Comment: The relevant optimization here is [*live-variable analysis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_variable_analysis) - a variable only needs storage available for it during its actual lifetime, i.e. between when it is first written and when it's last read.  This may be a proper subset of its nominal lifetime, i.e. when it's in scope.  Of course, in this case since `send_buf` is uninitialized, it's never written at all, so it really doesn't have a lifetime - you've broken the analysis with your UB and anything could happen.

Comment: Your "has already been allocated" might be an okay mental construct of what's happening, but under the "as if rule", the compiler is under no obligation to actually do the allocation at the point where the declaration occurs, so long as well-defined code couldn't tell the difference.  It only affects your code because your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Unfortunately, the Standard makes no effort to distinguish non-portable actions whose behavior should on most implementations be at least somewhat predictable from erroneous actions.  The notion that Undefined Behavior was meant to invite implementations to behave in weird and wacky fashions without regard for whether it might be more useful to extend the language by defining behaviors beyond what the Standard requires is a 21st-century invention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do not initialize objects in C (explicitly or implicitly), the C standard does not guarantee that they have any fixed values. Their values may be affected by any other circumstances and may even appear to vary on each use.

Since you do not initialize the array, the compiler may be allowing any other operations to affect it. That could include allowing the definition of `hello` to affect what values appear to be in `send_buf`. One fact that could be at play is the compiler does lifetime analysis of values. For example, in code such as:

```
int p;
int q = 4;
printf("%d\n", q);
p = 3;
printf("%d\n", p);
```

the compiler may see that, even though `p` is defined before `q`, there is never a “live” value in `p` at the same time as there is one in `q`, and therefore the compiler could use the same memory for `q` as it does for `p`. Similarly, the compiler may have decided that `send_buf` never contains live values at the same time as `hello`, so it could use the same memory for `hello` that it does for `send_buf`. Then, since you never put values in `send_buf`, getting the data that was in memory from `hello` is one possible behavior for your program.

A lesson to learn is that “weird” values appearing in an array in various circumstances are a clue that it may not have been initialized, and the remedy is to initialize it.

Comment: For that matter, even if you had written `int p = 3; int q = 4;` in the above example, the compiler could realize that the value `p=3` isn't needed until after `q` is dead, so it can reorder it into the code you wrote and again have them share memory.